# sum of rows win non-numeric colmun in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to Know haw many size small, large and extra large rows

```
ex : small 230 
     large 300 
     extra large 70
```

Comment: `avocados['size'].value_counts()`?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the [Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)